# Localize custom field values in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

How do I localize the custom field values in wordpress? I have these custom field values being displayed in the post through the RestAPI in wordpress using the JSON-API plugin.

What I'm trying to do is to localize these custom field. These values are being entered through the wordpress CMS, so when I goto my posts and have a query string (i.e. ?lang=es, where page will be translated into Spanish) in the url, it'll show the custom translated values.